# Launch startActivity() inside test.Jar , Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a jar file. jar file has 2 java files.first is simple java file and second is the android activity. first java file has a method in which we are going to the second activity. this jar file I am using in Cordova through a plugin. other methods of the jar are called successfully from Cordova plugin but in this method the second activity not launched. make sure I can call methods of the jar file I cant launch activity from the plugin. how to achieve this any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

add a `build.gradle` from `plugin.xml`

```
<framework src="src/android/build.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

under android platform. In `build.gradle`
add the require dependancies to launch an activity. Ex- `AppCompact`.

Note:- Activity must be created form code not from XML file.